# Customizing rich text editor toolbar in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hi is there any way to customize SharePoint 2010 rich text editor toolbar?

I don't need user to have all tools, just the one he needs like:

B, I, U, font type, font-size and couple more. but the rest of them I would like to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of attributes that you can add to your RichHtmlField tag in the Page Layout that controls some of those things: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richhtmlfield_members.aspx